# PHP pdo class getadresses warning and Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I followed a tutorial on creating a PDO class so I could understand both classes and PDO better.

I have followed the steps as laid out but the end result gave me 1 warning and a fatal error.

This was the error log:

> Warning:  PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known on line 24
>
> Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object on line 32

I'm not 100% sure what the reason for this error is, the comments on the tutorial seems to suggest it works for them, so I must of made a mistake some where.

This is my class function (see code comment to see which line the error is on)

```
class DB {
    private $host   = DB_HOST;
    private $user   = DB_USER;
    private $pass   = DB_PASS;
    private $dbname = DB_NAME;

    private $stmt;

    private $dbh;
    private $error;

    public function __construct(){
        // Set DSN
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;

        // Set options
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, 
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );      
        // Create a new PDO instanace
        try {
            // WARNING occurs here [line 24]
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        }// Catch any errors
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function query($query){
        // FATAL ERROR [line 34]
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }   

    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
        if (is_null($type)) {
          switch (true) {
            case is_int($value):
              $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
              break;
            case is_bool($value):
              $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
              break;
            case is_null($value):
              $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
              break;
            default:
              $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
          }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }

    public function execute(){
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    public function single(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

}
// Instantiate database.
$database = new DB();
define("DB_HOST", "secret");
define("DB_USER", "secret");
define("DB_PASS", "secret");
define("DB_NAME", "secret");
```

This is also an example of a select query I made to test my newly created class:

```
$database->query('SELECT name FROM users WHERE uid > :id');
$database->bind(':id', 0);
$row = $database->single(); //get the first row selected
echo "<pre>";
print_r($row);
echo "</pre>";
```

So i am unclear on what my mistake is here for my fatal error. Hoping some one can explain what mistake I made so I understand better.

Comment: where's the part wherein you provide the constructor with proper credentials? you haven't set those necessary properties yet

Comment: Do you mean the host, user, pass and database name? If so - it's at the bottom of the script.

Comment: you do have mysql installed, right?

Comment: @ElefantPhace yeah. I had been using PDO without a class for a while. But was getting tired of doing try catch every query so, wanted a class to simplify my code.

Comment: echo out `$dsn` and post what it looks like you can `xxx` out your info if it makes you feel better

Comment: @ElefantPhace do i echo it in the construct function?

Comment: yes right after you initialize it

Comment: `mysql:host=DB_HOST;dbname=DB_NAME` i am assuming this is suppose to have my actual values...

Comment: there's your problem, yep.

Comment: oh its below, i see now, its not supposed to be in there, it needs to be up top, it needs to be declared first before the class (instantiation). (i mean the definition of host, user, pass in your define functions)

Comment: or better, inside the class. But why bother? just set the variables in the class directly

Comment: Ah okay that solved it! @ElefantPhace thats true i might aswell contain them to be inside the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing defines before instantiating the class, like this:

```
    define("DB_HOST", "secret");
    define("DB_USER", "secret");
    define("DB_PASS", "secret");
    define("DB_NAME", "secret");

    // Instantiate database.
    $database = new DB();
```

And assign the defined values to the properties inside the "__construct" method, before any code:

```
    $this->host   = DB_HOST;
    $this->user   = DB_USER;
    $this->pass   = DB_PASS;
    $this->dbname = DB_NAME;
```

I hope this helps!